# Multidimensional arrays in Java. Without nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How I can print 2d or 3d array without nested loops (I wish use one loop)? Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202242/how-to-run-through-a-2d-array-with-a-single-loop

Comment: You can do it with no loops at all `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));`